# RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, gpio

When i execute with sudo python3 program.py and press de switch 1 throws the next exception:

```
Taking picture...
Picture takeng...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    if GPIO.input(switch1):
RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first
```

I use a raspberry cam library and rpi.gpio library for this project. Anyone knows what happend in my code ?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera

# initial config for gpio ports
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# input switches
switch1 = 22
switch2 = 23
switch3 = 24

# setup
GPIO.setup(switch1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(switch2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(switch3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# main loop
while True:
    if GPIO.input(switch1):
        print ("Taking picture...")
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            camera.capture("test.jpg")
        print ("Picture takeng...")
    elif GPIO.input(switch2):
        print ("Taking video...")
    elif GPIO.input(switch3):
        print ("Poweroff...")
        break

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have not set the pins to work as input and, when you try to access them as so, it fails. I had a similar problem and as far as I see it it should work (you are setting the pins after all).

Try changing `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` to `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)`. You will also have to change the pin numbers to the physical ones (yours would be 15, 16 and 18).
I still don't know why, but it did the trick on my code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give access permission to the `/dev/` folder and the `mem` file.
To do so open the raspberry terminal and enter the commands bellow

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/ and hit enter
```

then

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/mem and hit enter that's it
```